# PHP - print string with control characters

Tags: php

Is there any way to have PHP output a string with the \r\n and \n's as actual text instead of linebreaks? I'm seeing an interesting issue where an explode() on \n's isn't running properly on a Windows server...

EDIT: The \r\n's are coming from a user pressing enter when typing into a textarea so there's nothing for me to escape...

Comment: What do you mean by actual text?

Comment: Instead of an actual linebreak, have it actually output the characters "\n" for example...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), array('\n', '\r'), $input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape them before printing.

```
echo '\\r\\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try escaping your slashes with another slash?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array('\r', '\n'), $string);
```