# PHP: is there a way to see "invisible" characters like \n

Tags: php

Is there a way to see invisible characters like whitespace, newlines, and other non-printing characters in a manner like print_r() ?

Reason is there is some sort of character in my array that I can't see and breaking things.

```
Object Object
(
  [name] => name
  [numbers] => Array
      (
          [0] => 123

          [1] => 456
          [2] => 789
      )
   [action] => nothing
)
```

See the weird whitespace between [0] and [1]? When printing out [0] a newline gets printed as well. But no where do I assign a newline to [0] so I'm quite confused.

Is there a built in function in php that's like `show_invisible(Object->numbers[0])` and it will show `123\n` or similar?

Comment: View the output in a hex editor. Many good text editors have a hex mode.  It would be too much trouble I think, to convert it to hex in PHP just for debugging. I don't know of any function to display non-printables in a human-readable way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [addcslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) function:

> string addcslashes ( string $str, string $charlist )

which will return a string with backslashes before characters. An example would be:

> ```
> <?php
> echo addcslashes('foo[ ]', 'A..z');
> // output:  \f\o\o\[ \]
> // All upper and lower-case letters will be escaped
> // ... but so will the [\]^_`
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 68):

To see all the invisible characters not only `\r`, `\n` etc... It's good to see `json_encode`ed version and everything is clear:

```
$str = "...";
echo json_encode($str);
```

Comment: This was the simplest / easiest solution for me. Found the `\r` I was looking for.

Comment: But this will also encode `"` to `\"` and ``\`` to ``\\``, and accented letters like `ś` to `\u015b`

Answer (score 5):

You could probably list all the control characters out, but try this for a quick fix ?

[PHP - print string with control characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727955/php-print-string-with-control-characters)

It's a simple `str_replace("\n",'\n',$string)` kind of fix, but you could probably adapt the solution for a function callback on the array to convert those characters.

Answer (score 3):

You could just run your php script, and pipe it straight to `hexdump -C`

Answer (score 2):

To have an exact replication of the input string, without the surrounding `"` and without serialization, use this wrapper for [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php):

```
substr(json_encode((string)$string), 1, -1)
```

It does a string casting and removes the `"` of the JSON standard.