# Cast string to integer in PHP

Tags: php, string, casting, int

I've been trying to convert string to int in PHP to operate on it, but PHP keeps interpreting it as 0.

```
var_dump ($Pux); // output: string (6) "89"
```

I have tried several ways like

```
(int) $Pux,
intval($Pux)
settype($Pux, "integer")
```

But they all give me 0 instead of 89.

How should this be done?

Comment: @ManuelRamos: Are you sure the space didn't cause your error in the first place?

Comment: `intval($Pux)` seems to work for me. Are you sure this is the exact code you're running?

Comment: If you're casting, you'll have to reassign the result of that cast: `$pux = (int) $pux;`, That ought to work just fine. Don't forget to check `gettype($pux);` at any given time. You might be converting the type later on

Comment: Rolled back the edit, since I'd suspect that is the real cause for this problem.

Comment: @sanfor: OP commented saying the space isn't there in his actual code

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Omg, my bad, must've not read it carefully enough. Reverted my rollback. Thank you for notifying.

Comment: @sanfor: NP. I usually revert edits that might solve the issue, too. The OP said he'd edit the question himself anyway, but I took the liberty :P

Comment: `(int) $Pux;` needs to be `$Pux = (int) $Pux;`. Otherwise you don't actually write anything it it.

Comment: `string __(6)__ "89"` What are the 4 invisible bytes?

Comment: very suspicious for me var_dump ($Pux); // output: string (6) "89"  ? it should be string(2) !! use trim() before castring

Comment: [PHP: is there a way to see "invisible" characters like \n](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9345841/2943403)

Answer (score 3):

There is not problem if you dont put spaces between `$` and `varname` and assign the result of the cast to a variable.

```
<?php 
    $Pux = "89";
    var_dump ($Pux);
    $t = (int)$Pux;
    var_dump ($t);
?>
```

Output =

```
string(2) "89"
int(89)
```

Comment: See that 6 from the `var_dump()`: `string (6) "89"`. They probably have some html tags or hidden characters there, which may be the reason why it fails.

Comment: Mmmmm that sounds possible.

Comment: @Rizier123 Well I just tried adding spaces, then alphas and then odd ALT+12,ALT+13,ALT+14 type chars and it all still works just fine. Any others suggestions I can try.

Comment: html tags, e.g. `$str = "<xx>89";`

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes of course, put the rubbish at the front of the string and it goes nicely BANG

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert a string to a number:-

```
<?php
$Pux = "89"; // Or any other number
$Num = (int) $pux;
?>
```

If you are still getting a zero there might be some odd, invisible chars in front of the number. To test for that :-

echo "($Pux)";

Comment: You are coping on variable case sensitiveness right

Comment: OP commented the space between `$` and `Pux` isn't there in the actual code

Answer (score 0):

As `var_dump($Pux);` outputs `string(6) "89"` (not `string(2)`), it means your string contains **6 symbol**, I think they are 4 single brackets `(')` and `89`. So try to remove brackets from your string:

`$Pux = str_replace("'", '', $Pux);`

or remove double brackets too (for safe)

`$Pux = strtr($Pux, array("'" => '', '"' => ''));`

**EDITED**

will be good to remove all non numeric values:

```
$Pux = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $Pux);
```

and then convert to integer.

Thanks.

Comment: $PUx = strtr($PUx, array("'" => '', '"' => ''));    
$aux = intval($PUx);           
var_dump($aux);     output: int(0)

Comment: @ManuelRamos ,  what returns: $PUx = strtr($PUx, array("'" => '', '"' => '')); var_dump($PUx); ?

Comment: output: string(6) "89"

Comment: @ManuelRamos please run this code and share result 
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($PUx); $i++) {
var_dump($PUx[$i]); echo '<br>';
}

Comment: string(1) "<"

string(1) "t"

string(1) "d"

string(1) ">"

string(1) "8"

string(1) "9"

Comment: <td> html's tag was hidden

Comment: @ManuelRamos now its clear, at first remove all non numeric values: $PUx  = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $PUx); and then convert to integer.

Comment: I also hope I can help as I have you helped my

Answer (score 0):

The code below removes the non numeric characters::

```
function numeric( $st_data )
    {
        $st_data = preg_replace("([[:punct:]]|[[:alpha:]]| )",'',$st_data);
        return $st_data;    
    }
```

Comment: Better use \D or [^0-9] for the search, as this matches all non-digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to integer in two ways:

[Typecasting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) or
 [intval function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
<?php
 $pux = "89";
 var_dump($pux);
 $pux = (int) $pux;
 var_dump($pux);
 $pux = "89";
 $pux =  intval($pux);
 var_dump($pux);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake.
Indeed when i  did var_dump($myvar).
it returns string(2) "89"
and when i did all the casts fonctions it returned me 0.
I search and finally the answer is in this page.
So I share with you what i learned.
You have just to do a regex php : **$myvar = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]","",$myvar)**. It removes all the not number in your string (in my case the string(2)).

Comment: I missed a / in the end od the regex    $myvar = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/","",$myvar)

Comment: You can edit your answer at any time.