# Print special characters like \s or \n as '\s' or '\n'

Tags: php, regex

I have a string of text with whitespace and newlines. Sometimes tabs. e.g.

```
$text = 'Hello I am    chunk  of text
        A new line follows';
```

I'm then doing some matching with preg_match.

For example:

```
preg_match('/Hello I am\s*/',$a,$b);
```

But before I do that, I'd like to see exactly what kind of spacing is in this $text string so I would like to see what regex sees, otherwise I'm doing a fair bit of trial and error. My real $text string is actually far more complex and sometimes has tabs newlines and I have a suspicion some sort of separation I'm unaware of. So I'd like to see what regex sees, for example:

```
Hello\sI\am\tchunk\s\sof\stext\nA\snew\sline\sfollows
```

It doesn't translate the spaces and tabs and new lines but prints what they are. How is this done? I want to see what php sees when I through this $text string into a preg_match. Thanks

Comment: Why `\s`? `\s` means any whitespace.

Comment: Use [`addcslashes`](http://php.net/addcslashes) for escaping linebreaks. Or [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) for substituting spaces as well.

Comment: No matter what you do you won't get a newline from that string, since it doesn't contain any. You've just concatenated two strings. `$text` contains, among other things, the "word" `textA`.

Comment: Also the text between `am` and `chunk` is 4 whitespace, not a tab.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the newline :)

Comment: You have 2 line breaks there technically. Is the one after the `<br />` not really present?... or should it be `text\n\nA`? Something like this I think could work `str_replace(array(' ', "\t", "\n"), array('\s', '\t', '\n'), $text);` unless you want to account for HTML formatting elements.

Comment: I'm scraping with simple_html_dom then getting out the pieces with regex. simple_html_dom has a function which converts a chunk of html into plaintext, so br's and tabs and spaces etc are no longer html. It's a bit of a trial and error process at the moment since I don't know exactly when there is a space or tab in the chunks I'm processing. Basically I would like to see what regex sees because it  doesn't see a space or newline, it sees \s and \n etc as well as other stuff I can't see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: is there a way to see "invisible" characters like \n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345841/php-is-there-a-way-to-see-invisible-characters-like-n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see newline characters (and maybe others) by using `json_encode()`

```
$string = 'something
            something';

echo json_encode($string);

// outputs something \nsomething
```