# Message: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (21/12/2020) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$start = new DateTime(21/12/2020);
```

while executing this statement, it gives following error:
Type: Exception

Message: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (21/12/2020) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character

What could be the reason for this error and what is the solution for it?

Comment: Might be an invisible character at the beginning of the date string. Where is this date string coming from?

Comment: @El_Vanja I have tried using trim(), but didn't worked.It is coming through html form via ajax call to controller)

Comment: Trimming works for whitespace, but not for some characters that aren't displayed, but are part of the string. Where does this value come from?

Comment: It is coming through html form via ajax call to controller

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345841/php-is-there-a-way-to-see-invisible-characters-like-n), it has instructions on detecting invisible characters.

Comment: After all I exploded string and setup as YYYY-MM-DD and it worked.

Comment: $start = new DateTime("21/12/2020");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace slashes with dots or slash slashed (like 21\/12\/2020). Better don't use slashes in that context.