# How to echo line endings in php?

Tags: php, line-endings

I did not ask about `How to replace \r & \n with <br/>?`, I need to know how to dump line endings.

I have a script that handles post data incoming from users that fill a form. How can I dump line endings if the data may contain different types of ones (CR, CRLF, LF)?

When using the `var_dump` function, it displays something like

```
string(3) "


"
```

And the second question: what happens if users have different OS? Will a browser send different types of line endings that are typical for these OS?

Comment: for html you need to use a `<br>` tag whitespace (including newlines) is collapsed when rendering html in the browser. (View source and you will see your newlines are alive and well)

Comment: If the output is a webpage, then you'll need to use `<br>` mostly, not CR/LF combinations. Browsers typically send network linebreaks (CRLF).

Comment: as usual "be liberal in what you receive, strict in what you output". expect to get ANY kind of line endings, and convert as necessary.

Comment: So, are you saying you want to actually see the \n? You could do str_replace(array("\r\n","\n\r","\r","\n"),"\\n\n",$str), which would replace all occurrences of line breaks with a visible \n (thanks to the double slash), and a new line. Or for more control, you might be able to use a preg_replace, or something.

Comment: @Jakar, yes I asked about that. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If your question was about converting CR/LF back to escapes for visualization, then the better references would be: [PHP - print string with control characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6727955), or: [PHP: is there a way to see "invisible" characters like \n](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9345841)